# Visualizing the meaning of a complex determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant, visualization

**Context:** A [common visualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#2_%C3%97_2_matrices) of the meaning of a (real) determinant is the area (or volume, in higher dimensions) enclosed by the image of basis vectors under matrix transformation:

[image]

**Question:** But what if the matrix and determinant in question are complex valued?  How do we visualize the meaning of the determinant of these cases?

**Example:** For example, the determinant of a unitary matrix $U$ satisfies

$$
\det(U) = e^{i\phi}
$$

for some $\phi$.  Is there a way to visualize what the complex determinant of $U$ is, in this case?